# How to lock touchpad while typing

Tags: synaptics

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on Dell Inspiron N5110. As the touch pad is a bit large in this model it’s frequently getting in my way while typing. Although I try my best to not touch it, the cursor still  gets moved and ruins what I am typing.

I remember an option in the "Mouse and Touchpad" utility which let us lock the touchpad while we are typing but I couldn't find that option in this utility now.

Any clue?

Answer (score 15):

Use syndaemon to disable while typing.  Syntax is `syndaemon [-i idle-time] [-d]`
So something like `syndaemon -i 4 -d`  Or, you could disable it completely with this command `synclient TouchpadOff=1`
Add them to your startup applications

Comment: This solution works with all Desktops and Window Managers, xubuntu lubuntu kubuntu, gnome xfce kde fluxbox icewm. Great job.

Comment: syndaemon -i .5 -K -t -R -d will just disable clicking, while allowing movement

Answer (score 5):

I could fix this using dconf-editor, under `org > gnome > settings daemon > peripherals > touchpad`. There's an option to disable the touchpad while typing.

[image]

I also don't have the "touchpad" tab in system settings. Let me know if works for you.

UPDATE: I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and the "touchpad tab" issue is fixed. At least with my laptop.

Comment: Not working under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I found it in Ubuntu 18.04 under `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/`.

Answer (score 4):

Open System Settings.

Go to "Mouse and Touchpad"

Click on the Touchpad tab.

mark "Disable touchpad while typing."

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Tcouhpad tab. I do remember this tab as this is actually what I used in past but it's not available now.

Comment: what's your output of `xinput list`

Comment: ⎡ Virtual core pointer             id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer   id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint      id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: I think it has detected it as ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint

Comment: I have the "disable touchpad while typing" option CHECKED and still I'm having problems. What's wrong? Mine is an integrated Synaptics PS/2 touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find that the mouse an touchpad settings that come with Ubuntu don't quite do the job and my mouse is always moving around. I use the following program to manually turn off the touchpad when I want. Not quite as elegant as turning off when typing, but for me much more effective.

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

All above suggestions did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I have some touchpad settings in the Settings application, but not a checkbox to disable the touchpad while typing. I did found it with `dconf-editor`, but it was already enabled, making no difference.

I opened **Startup Applications** and added `syndaemon -i .5 -K -t -R -d` to turn off the touchpad 500 milliseconds (`.5`) after every keystroke:

[image]