# Syndaemon disable keyboard while typing not working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, hp, 18.04

I really love Ubuntu 18.04, but something is driving me nuts. Every time I'm typing and I accidentally touch the touchpad, my typing cursor jumps. On [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85065/how-to-lock-touchpad-while-typing) I found that this behavior can be solved in two ways:

- By using `syndaemon`
- By using the `touchbar-indicator` plugin

But on my system both methods seem to fail. For the `touchbar-indicator`, I just enabled the "auto disable touchpad" option, but that doesn't do anything. Then I configured `syndaemon` as a startup application like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && syndaemon -i .8 -K -t -R -d"
```

If anyone knows what I can do about this behavior please tell me since I'm going mad. :p

Thanks a lot in advance

**System info:**
- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8 
- HP Zbook G3 Studion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

1. By using this [forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1150319) I fully reinstalled my xserver drivers.
2. I then reinstalled the drivers following this [forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin).
3. I then added the following command to my startup applications:

   - `syndaemon -i .5 -K -t -R -d`

This disables tapping (`-t`) on my trackpad for half a second (`-i`) after any non-modifier+ (<kbd>Shift</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>Super</kbd>) (`-K`, vs `-k`) with the XRecord extension (`-R`), and to keep this service running in the background (`-d`).

You may try adjusting to your liking, and dropping the `-R` flag.

Comment: FYI, my Toshiba R705-P35 (Debian Jessie) required the `-R` option. Said command is in a file named **/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98x11-syndaemon**...