# Keyboard and touchpad stopped working after messing up with drivers

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I am new to Ubuntu and using 18.04 LTS. My touchpad wasn't working fine and the palm rejection didn't seem to work at all, so I did the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085390/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-while-typing-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo reboot
```

After the system reboot, the touchpad and keyboard stopped working alltogether.

What should I do to restore them?

Also before messing up with my driver my touchpad was using Synaptic drivers.

Comment: @mchid I can't because none of my keyboard or mouse is working,external keyboard or mouse doesn't work too.

Comment: See if you can get to a tty by pressing CTRL+ALT+F3 and if you can't, follow [these instructions on how to boot into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and then reinstall synaptic from the console. This should allow access to run commands before the drivers even load.

Comment: @mchid I enterd the recovery mode and tried to intall but it can't resolve the link.How do I make it connect to the network

Comment: It should be `sudo systemctl start network-manager` or just `systemctl start network-manager` if you are running as root or try `restart` instead of `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get to a tty by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and if you can't, follow [these instructions on how to boot into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) This should allow access to run commands before the drivers even load.

Once you boot into recovery mode and after you run the command to switch to read-write mode, run the following command to reinstall synaptic:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

---

As for your touchpad problem (after you reinstall synaptics), you can modify the parameters of your touchpad device by using `xinput` commands or by modifying your synaptics configuration file.

```
xinput list
```

should list your devices and each device will have an "id" number.

For example, your touchpad may be listed as device id=12.

Then, you would run:

```
xinput list-props 13
```

This will list available parameters. Each parameter will have a number in parenthesis followed by setting values like 1,1 or something like that. To change the setting values, you would run a command like this (to set device 13, parameter 282, to a value of 1):

```
xinput 13 282 1
```

Search for xinput and libinput commands and settings for more information. Also, this won't be persistent so you'll have to run this as a startup script or locate the default settings file.

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to connect to a network, you can startup NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

and if you don't have a network setup, you can [follow these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) to set up a new wireless or ethernet connection.

Comment: Upon running the command 'sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics', an error message is displayed that says it cannot fetch and resolve the link containing .in.archive.ubuntu.com .I guess It need an internet connection but how to load the network drivers