# how i can disable touchpad when i enter words

Tags: drivers, touchpad

The touchpad is not from Synaptics. When I enter words, I touch the touchpad with my palm and it annoys me. Does anyone know a utility to disable the touchpad while typing keys. Thank you

Comment: Just to make sure we get it right: you do _not_ want to disable the touchpad in general, but _only_ when typing - but when not typing, it should be enabled?
Except that, please edit your question and add details which Ubuntu release and version you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the touchpad while typing](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085401/767056)

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
    syndaemon - a program that monitors keyboard activity and disables the touchpad when the keyboard is being used
```

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: man syndaemon - it's a really short documentation